# Can I omit optional parameter in laravel routing?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

here's code:

```
Route::get('diagram', 'DiagramController@showDiagram');
Route::get('diagram/{type}', 'DiagramController@showDiagram');
Route::get('diagram/{type}/{template}', 'DiagramController@showDiagram');
Route::get('diagram/{type}/{template}/{offset}', 'DiagramController@showDiagram');
```

and here's how I want it to look like:

```
Route::get('diagram/{type}/{template}/{offset}', 'DiagramController@showDiagram');
```

Is there a way to tell Laravel that all of the above parameters don't have to be given in url? Or do I have to declare it like above in four lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627864/laravel-4-how-to-pass-multiple-optional-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write four line for that, check the [Routing documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-optional-parameters) on Laravel.

So in your case, you could write

```
Route::get('diagram/{type?}/{template?}/{offset?}', 'DiagramController@showDiagram');
```

You just add a `?` at the end of each optional parameters.